# How would I go about calculating the sum of numbers in a linked list, in a certain range, recursively?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, linked-list

Let's say I need to calculate the sum of all the values in a linked list recursively, but I must add 0 for any number greater than or equal to 50.

I've run into a problem in my base case, where I'm not sure exactly how I would correctly calculate the sum. It always stops iterating anytime it hits a number greater than 50. Like so:

```
def sumNodes(linkedList):
    ptr = linkedList
    if ptr['data'] >= 50:
        return 0
    return ptr['data'] + sumNodes(ptr['next'])


y = {'data': 2, 'next': {'data': 3, 'next': {'data': 4, 'next': {'data': 100, 'next': {'data': 45, 'next': {'data': 200, 'next': {'data': 6, 'next': None}}}}}}}

sumNodes(y)
```

This returns me a value of 9, and I'm not sure how to keep iterating through the linked list in these types of situations. I'm sure there's a way to keep iterating while returning 0. I've already tried putting a recursive call in the if statement, but it returns an error. I'm quite stuck here.

Comment: Typically, you'd separate the first element from the rest of the list (y and ys), then if ys is non-empty, do `return y + sumNodes(ys)`. In your case though, you need to check if y is greater than 50, and if it is, you can either change it to 0, or go through a separate "leg" that doesn't add it on. Right now, as soon as it hits 0, it returns. Try instead changing `return 0` to `return 0 + ptr['next'] `

Comment: And you don't have a proper base case. When linkedList is empty, return 0 at the top of the function.

Comment: When you say go through a separate "leg", what do you mean? And I've tried changing it to: `return 0 + ptr['next']`, but it gives me an error saying:


`TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: By leg, I meant another return statement, instead of just modifying the value. And it looks like it can't infer the type of linkedList. Your use of a dictionary as a linked list is weird; i wouldn't be surprised if that's what's tripping it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the current value in a temp variable, and set it to zero if required:

```
def sumNodes(linkedList):
    ptr = linkedList
    tmp = ptr['data']
    if tmp >= 50:
        tmp = 0

    return tmp + sumNodes(ptr['next'])
```

Never used python so may be typos, but the idea should hopefully help.

You also need to cater for a zero length list and return zero, as per @carcigenicate's comment above.